# How do I write a ternary statement in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I translate a ternary statement written in the WebformsViewEngine (.aspx) to Razor (.cshtml)?

```
<%= (value <= 5) ? do A : do B %>
```

Comment: This is called "ternary operator"

Comment: Whats `do` supposed to be?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz, just dummy function for sake of demo. But I got it now.

Comment: Why would this be -1 for not knowing what it's called? Thought this was a forum to help people. Please motivate.

Comment: I think I have a good idea of who it is. Rules also say that downvoting should be motivated. Live by the rules you dictate youself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This translates to:

```
@(value <= 5 ? do A : do B)
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement you have written in your Question is in 'ASPX' format

But you need to use Razor syntax instead of that with  `@`

Using `@` symbol you can write any expression like::

```
@(Model.value<=5? do A: do B)
```